# Export message encounter 500 - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, ews-managed-api

Grap API and EWS-managed API have different response behavior in a message.

By using graph API `GET messages/m_id`

I could successfully get message infomation

But when I using EWS-managed API to export mail:

> http code 500
>
> An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Index was
>   outside the bounds of the array.

It seems that the graph and EWS-managed API do not sync data.

The issued message on office 365 UI show that:

> om dit bericht opnieuw te verzenden (to resend this message)

How could I deal with this?

1. The response in ews API is too general to verify
2. How about the real status of this mail?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Microsoft Graph and EWS API?

Comment: At first we only use Graph, but it could not support all functionalities like export mail or import mail, so we combined two.

Comment: Hi @JeremyThakeMSFT, do you have any comment about this issue? How should I handle this response? Thank you so much!